# how can i use PHP forking on a web server?

Tags: php

i made this website that uses scraping than insert data in MySQL db , to make scraping faster i tried to use threading but i read that you can't use threading on a webserver so i tried forking but the server response with 502 Bad Gateway

in the file Proc.php we have a basic scraping for a website products then inserting them but nothing was insterted in the db so the problem either in taking arguments or creating the process :

```
      for ( $i=0 ; $i < 6 ; $i++ )
        { 
$pipe[$i] = popen('php -q Proc.php -p='.$Product.'-x='.$x.'-i='.$i, 'w'); }
        
        $i = 0 ;
        $Q = "Select count(Name) From S_LOG Where User='$x' ; " ;
        
        do {
        sleep(10 - $i );
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $Q) ;
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) ;
        $i -= 1 ;}
        while ( $row[0] != 5 ) ;
        
        for ( $i=0 ; $i < 6 ; $i++ )
        { pclose($pipe[$i]); }
```

taking arguments in Proc.php :

```
$options = getopt("p:x:i:");

$x       = $options['x'] ;
$Product = $options['p'] ;
$id      = $options['i'] ;
```

Comment: What is the value of `$pipe[$i]`? (use `var_dump()`)

Comment: the value of pipes is NULL

Comment: Why does it need to be fast ? Is it realtime or are you scrapping large number of products ? or Both ?

Comment: @Gameek Please edit your question to include the new `var_dump()` line and the output you get. The return value of `popen()` shouldn't be `NULL`.

Comment: exactly , both realtime and ( the amont of products depends on user's search )

Comment: turns out that the hosting is disabling the uage of `popen`